# CSS Style scrolling text but displayed between each time it goes by, (like how some music players do)

Tags: html, css

```css
.example1 {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.example1 h3 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: limegreen;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
  animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
}


/* Move it (define the animation) */

@-moz-keyframes example1 {
  25% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes example1 {
  25% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <h3>Scrolling text... </h3>
</div>
```

I want this but I want the keyframe animation to start at left aligned margin

reallylo (this is the example of the start of a scrolling filename that is more than 8 characters long as an example not a mispelled word)

pause for 0-25%

25-100%:

allylong

lylongte

longtext

ngtext

text

xt

make sure it is white here

and loop

I want to add more details but I am unsure what else to say?

Comment: Have u fixed that yet ?

Answer (score 0):

```
.example1 {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.example1 h3 {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: limegreen;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
  animation: example1 10s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  33% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  66% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  66% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes example1 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  33% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  66% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
/* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    /* Firefox bug fix */
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

<div class="example1">
  <h3>Scrolling text... </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: im unsure how to format it but this seems to work (by format i mean so that code run shows up)